# Pop_Up Modal Validation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this issue with validating form before ajax.post, i cant get the pop_up to validate, i have read many posts about similar issue but non of the solutions worked for me. i am not sure what is wrong with the code.

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

         <div class="modal fade" id="PGModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                        <h4 id="PGModalTitle"></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="PGform">

                            <fieldset id="SubmitPGform">
                                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.HR_Setup_PayGradeVMId, new { @id = "PayGradeVMId" })
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.HR_SetupId, new { @id = "SetupId", @Value = ViewBag.SetupId })

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Name:</label>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "Name", @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Range Start:</label>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RangeStart, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "RangeStart", @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RangeStart, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Range End:</label>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RangeEnd, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "RangeEnd", @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RangeEnd, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="SavePayGradeRecord">Save</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCloseIt" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>

                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    @section scripts
        {
        <script type="text/javascript">



            $(function () {
                LoadPayGrades();

            });


            //Show The Popup Modal For Add New PayGrade
            function AddNewPayGrade() {

                $("#PGform")[0].reset();
                $("#PayGradeVMId").val(0);
                $("#PGModalTitle").html("Add New Pay Grade");
                $("#PGModal").modal();
            }

            //Show The Popup Modal For Edit PayGrade Record
            function EditPayGrade(id) {

                $("#PGModalTitle").html("Update Pay Grade Record");
                $("#PGModal").modal();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetPayGradeById", "PayGrade")/' + id,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                        $("#PayGradeVMId").val(obj.HR_Setup_PayGradeVMId);
                        $("#Name").val(obj.Name);
                        $("#RangeStart").val(obj.RangeStart);
                        $("#RangeEnd").val(obj.RangeEnd);
                    }
                })
            }

            //Save Pay Grade Data to Database
            $("#SavePayGradeRecord").click(function ()
            {

                $("#PGform").validate({
                    rules: {
                        Name: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 2
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        Name: {
                            required: "Name Required",
                            minlength: "Minumum 2 charactors"
                        }
                    },
                    submitHandler: function (form) {
                        var data = $("#SubmitPGform").serialize();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("CreatePayGrade", "PayGrade")',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: data,
                            success: function (response) {
                                $("#PGModalTitle").html("");
                                location.reload();
                                $("#PGModal").modal("hide");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

            })

        </script>
    }
```

i have the following Lib in my Layout.

```
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Tried few suggestions on stackoverflow, 
[Validate form before Bootstrap modal popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914792/validate-form-before-bootstrap-modal-popup)

Debugging Crome i am getting .validate is not a function, however the form displays message of data annotation of the view model, and not messages of the validation Jquery, form does not submit the ajax post.
any ideas for a solution, i can do my own validation function and use it before ajax post, but i thought if this is something built it why not use it.

Comment: You have to add the jquery unobtrusive js script reference to the modal view like you did for google and cloudflare. For some reason MVC doesn't pick up the rendered script file for unobtrusive.

Comment: added<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script> still no change, same issue validate is not a function and form not submitting.

Comment: So you have the minified version of the unobtrusive file being rendered in your layout here: @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") yet your referencing some other jquery library as your source here:<script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/…>?? Your script should be something like: <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

Comment: I tried keeping them in layout only, didn't work, added them into view directly didn't work, did duplicate (view + layout) did not work..

Comment: If you have two different validation libraries you'll get conflicts. What console errors are showing in your browser?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (Index:315)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-1.10.2.js:5109)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-1.10.2.js:47

Comment: If you remove the cloudflare reference and add the mvc unobtrusive to the child (modal) it should work.